# Install Meteorite in Linux Using Meteor?

Tags: meteor, centos, meteorite

I need to know about install meteorite package in linux(Cent O.S) using Meteor.I'm try to using mrt & npm but i get errors like mrt not found and npm not found.I am new to meteor.So can you please suggest me how to use mrt and npm packages in Meteor?The below ones are using to install meteorite.

```
npm install -g meteorite
sudo -H npm install -g meteorite
```

The above both are get errors are npm is not found.

I'm using Ubuntu but get the below error :

```
[root@localhost HCare]# sudo apt-get install nodejs nodejs-dev npm
sudo: apt-get: command not found
[root@localhost HCare]#
```

The above both are get errors are npm is not found. And i'm using yum -y update and also get so many below messages but this is correct or not but i dont know?

```
Another app is currently holding the yum lock; waiting for it to exit...
  The other application is: PackageKit
    Memory : 2.4 M RSS (356 MB VSZ)
    Started: Sat Mar 22 06:41:50 2014 - 3 day(s) 12:13:19 ago
    State  : Sleeping, pid: 6457
```

and also does not exit and get a lot above messages.

Comment: Which linux are you planning on installing it on?

Comment: I'm using the linux is Cent O.S.@ archie hicox

Comment: You also need to install `npm` & `nodejs`. It would depend the linux you have, but if you use ubuntu you could use : http://blog.nodeknockout.com/post/65463770933/how-to-install-node-js-and-npm

Comment: @Venkat for CentOS: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-and-run-a-node-js-app-on-centos-6-4-64bit up and until the point where they tell you to make an express app

Comment: @Venkat: Regarding your new edit - you dont't need sudo as a root. Just use `apt-get install nodejs nodejs-dev npm`

Comment: **You must be using a different Linux distro.** `apt-get` is for Ubuntu. Your terminal doesn't look like an Ubuntu (I don't remember Ubuntu had `[]` for the terminal), and `apt-get` missing (it's supposed to be built-in)

Comment: Can you please see the post and try to execute as you told above document get so many messages but not terminating.@ Akshat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using the package manager for your distribution, in this case YUM:

1. Install nodejs and npm: `yum install nodejs npm`
2. Install meteorite `npm install -g meteorite`

Since you got meteor already installed, that's it.

Comment: I'm trying use above things gets this messages a lot so this is the way to instal                       `Another app is currently holding the yum lock; waiting for it to exit...
 The other application is: PackageKit
    Memory : 2.4 M RSS (356 MB VSZ)
    Started: Sat Mar 22 06:41:50 2014 - 3 day(s) 12:09:20 ago
    State  : Sleeping, pid: 6457`.@archie hicox

Comment: You should be able to solve this problem with: 1. `yum clean all` 2. `rpm --rebuilddb` and retry. Also close any graphical YUM manager.

Comment: also get look like as same.@ archie hicox

Comment: The package manager seems to be running in the background. Remove its process with the mentioned ID: `kill -9 6457`

Comment: Using kill -9 6457.Now get `Another app is currently holding the yum lock; waiting for it to exit...` like so many this is also not terminating.@ archie hicox

Comment: Can you please suggest me what mistake i can do.I didn't get any idea about this.These all are executing in terminal window in linux.@ archie hicox

Comment: The problem is that the packagemanager is updating in the background. The service is always running even if you kill the process.

Comment: Still Running.@ archie hicox

Comment: You can disable PackageKit with `gpk-prefs &disown` and change "Check for updates" to "Never".

Comment: Okay what i can do for this problem.Can you please suggest me?.@ archie hico

Comment: I'm try to executing is gpk-prefs &disow but get error command not found.@archie hicox

Comment: Have you tried restarting the machine? Sometimes this can be the fastest solution...

Comment: Okay I restarted my machine now i can execute `yum install nodejs npm` or any else.@ archie hicox

Comment: I have one doubt , These all are executing in Current app terminal window or any else.@archie hicox

Comment: The packages are installed globally for all users.

Comment: Okay I'm also Doing same not in current app Directory.@ archie hicox

Comment: Yes, it shouldnt matter in which directory you're installing packages through YUM.

Comment: Can i download anything for YUM.@ archie hicox

Comment: Just executing above statements or any files i can download.@ archie hicox

Comment: You can list all available (and installable) packages through YUM: `yum list available`. You can also list all the installed ones: `yum list installed`. The sky is the limit.

Comment: I reverted your question to the original problem, since you changed it to address different issues that came up along the way. This is reflected by this discussion here. If you found my answer helpful, you can accept it for your original question.